# Include build-time features with project references

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

I have a project, `MyProject.csproj` that contains some code as well as other assets. The assets need build time transformation before being compiled. To do this, I have a sidekick project, `MyProject.BuildTime.csproj` that contains the code.

Now the question is, can I somehow add MSBuild targets etc to `MyProject.BuildTime.csproj` so that it suffices to simply add a reference to it to have it picked up at compile time. `MyProject.BuildTime.csproj` is not shipped and would be referenced with private assets.

I know it is possible to include *.targets files with NuGet packages, but I haven't been able to find out if the same is true with project references. The naive approach of just adding the .targets file to `MyProject.BuildTime.csproj` doesn't work.

To state the obvious, I am of course aware that I can add the targets file directly to `MyProject.csproj` which is what I do now. I am simply looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: You can create a separate file for targets and share it between projects (in the same way, how it's done in .net SDK)

Comment: You mean importing the same target file explicitly? If so, that is what I do. I just wonder if there is a way to automatically import like for PackageReference?